# Strategies for taking data from one entity to another from when certain time range matches

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, backend, typeorm

I have entities like

**Order**

- id
- total price
- user_id
- vendor_id
- status (enum: accepted, rejected, ready, ....)
- viable_pickup_time (UTC timestamp without timezone )

**Gig**

- id
- gig_price

I have to take order to gig when it in certain status (ie. ready) and if viable_pickup_time is within than say 1hour of current UTC time

What is the best strategy for this?

backend library I used are: Express, typeorm (postgres)

Should I have another server running a cron-job (node-cron) just to check the neccessary condition or is there any other efficient or standard process for this kind of work?

I don't know if publisher and subscribe of postgres (subscriber of Typeorm) is fit for this task.

Comment: Use the timestamp range datatype, tsrange: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html

Comment: Does it gives some trigger for node app to logically update that particular order_id to be in gig?